# Multipart requests in httpclient 4.4: Custom Content-Disposition header for each part

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

When I make a multipart HTTP request using httpclient 4.4:

```
HttpClientBuilder hcBuilder = HttpClientBuilder.create();
RequestBuilder reqBuilder = RequestBuilder.post();
MultipartEntityBuilder meb = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
ContentType contentType = ...;
String body = ...;
StringBody sb = new StringBody(body, contentType);
reqBuilder.setEntity(meb.build());
HttpUriRequest req = reqBuilder.build();
httpClient = hcBuilder.build();
HttpResponse http_res = httpClient.execute(req);
```

The request is built as:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 123
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=4gzd6246Ar7-0tL4z8wXxJFc3qeR8_GaSoQtF
Host: localhost:10101
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.4 (java 1.5)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate

--4gzd6246Ar7-0tL4z8wXxJFc3qeR8_GaSoQtF
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="str-name"

Hello World
--4gzd6246Ar7-0tL4z8wXxJFc3qeR8_GaSoQtF--
```

Using httpclient 4.4, is there any way of setting the `Content-Disposition` header value for the part to any arbitrary value (default generated by httpclient is `form-data`)?

Answer (score 2):

```
FormBodyPart bodyPart = FormBodyPartBuilder.create()
        .setName("blah")
        .addField("Content-Disposition", "blah")
        .setBody(new StringBody("blah", ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN))
        .build();
HttpEntity entity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create()
        .addPart(bodyPart)
        .build();
entity.writeTo(System.out);
```

produces

```
--nlHhbHgLGuf9bkSZJ1wR6aSFn5tT6K
Content-Disposition: blah
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

blah
--nlHhbHgLGuf9bkSZJ1wR6aSFn5tT6K--
```